# Run Rmarkdown.rmd outside R editor

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am still pretty new to R, but couldn't seem to find solution to my question.
It's quite simple:

I have a .rmd file written and ready to run, but instead of openning it from R or Rstudio, Is there a way I can knit it automatically without opening that file?

Please kindly guide me how should I do this, screenshot would be much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

Added: So I took nrussell's advice and tried run that on my windows command line, but I am seeing "The filename, directory name, or volumn label syntax is incorrect"[image]. Thoughts? Thank you all for your comments!

Comment: I am asking something similar to "right click ---Batch Submit with SAS", thanks again.

Comment: Did you look in rStudio under file -> knit?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I want to do this WITHOUT opening Rstudio. Maybe something like a WINDOWS Command ?

Comment: Could you clarify if you actually have R installed (and you simply don't want to invoke it)? Or do you not have it installed and so don't want to have to install it?

Comment: Just like you would call any other R function from the command line, e.g. `Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("/path/to/your/file.Rmd")'`.

Comment: doctorG: yes, I have R and Rstudio installed, but I don't want to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

did a cd RMD's path , then used  @nrussell's code. and it worked.

Somehow, I couldn't use specified RMD file path such as C:\XXX\XXXX.rmd, but if I cd to there first, it worked.